# How do I find out which tables are modified by a cascaded deletion in Derby?

Tags: java, derby, cascading-deletes, in-memory-database

I have the need to obtain the names of modified tables caused by the cascade deletion. It happens that the DB in use is the latest version of [derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/index.html) 10.8 in the in-memory mode.

The reason for this requirement is that by knowing the table names, I can flush the data in them into CSV files. Because the data is in memory, it should be persisted into CSV files when modified.

So you can use any sort of tech (Java or SQL) to achieve it. But I want the cheapest one.
I don't want to manually maintain the FK relationship in my code, because it seems it's duplicated with the DDL. Also it seems I need to consider if the related table really has related records with the master table.

So do I have to query if there is related records or should I manually delete those records in related table so that it can be a workaround?

To be simple, what's the **cheapeast** way to do this?

Cheap here means the easiest and fastest one.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

**Note.** 
This is used in an IDE. So after the update, users need to see the CSV files being modified just after that update, otherwise it will cause confusion.

Comment: Doesn't having an update-on-change data store on disk kind of defeat the purpose of an in-memory database?  Why not just use derby's disk-storage mode?

Comment: Because csv files are the required format.

Comment: Can you not just dump the data in the on-disk derby database into CSV files periodically?

Comment: No. You are not sure if the user just close the java process and you lose the data in memory. I can dump out all tables but more precisely control is required. Also it's out of topic!!

Comment: Also in memory database is certainly faster!

Comment: An in-memory database where you write out **complete tables** on **every update** is *not* going to be faster than a properly-optimized disk-storage database.  Not by a long shot.

Comment: I suggest you put a complete solution in the answer,so we can see if your point makes sense or not. Dump the data in the on-disk derby database into CSV files periodically is a very bad idea.

Comment: *Why* is it a bad idea?  If the application is closed, the derby database will still exist on disk.  No data would be lost.  The CSV files just might not be up to date.  (But note that you could catch the event of the application being closed and perform a dump to CSV before terminating to make sure that the CSV data *is* up to date.)

Comment: It's not web application. But it is used in a IDE like eclipse.